# VBA,Type mismatch , using Variable within Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple code where I am trying to take a dynamic range and paste to another workbook.
But I believe the types within my range selection as causing me to get a `type mismatch` error on line `sValue = wbTarget.Sheets(1).Range("B4:AE" & LastRow).Value`

Can anyone help with this?

```
Sub Update()

Dim sPath As String
Dim sValue As String
Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim strName As String

strName = ActiveSheet.Name ' Explicitly provide the sheet name
sPath = ""   'Parent Path of Pasting to file
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("")  'Workbook copying from
LastRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheets("BusinessDetails").Cells(Rows.Count, "AE").End(xlUp).Row)
sValue = wbTarget.Sheets(1).Range("B4:AE" & LastRow).Value

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("Ao2").Value = sValue
ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim sValue() as Variant`, then `Resize` on the next line... see http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx

Comment: @BigBen , thanks! not sure on how to do the resizing bit though.

Comment: The link I provided has an example.